# How to hide paldom spinning dialog in phonegap when page loading completed?

Tags: cordova, dialog, cordova-plugins

I have succeeded in showing a spinner dialog, but I am unable to stop
or hide when page fully loaded in phonegap apps. I have tried this code below, it continuously shows spinning until I touch anywhere outside of the dialog. I want it to get hidden automatically when the page is fully loaded. How to hide spinner dialog beside show it automatically when page load completed?

// Show spinner dialog

```
 window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show();
```

// (Android only)

```
 window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show("title","message
```

Comment: There is only one info left: What framework or other helping tools do you use? Jquery mobile, Ionic, Sencha.... It depends on how to check for page loading events

Comment: Using Paldom/SpinnerDialog in PhoneGap for Android

Comment: When you still provide this code that builds up your page (ajax-calls, sqlite-queries etc), then I can help you.